# Mac OS X VirtualBox Update to 10.6.6

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I was able to get Mac OS X 10.6.2 to work on my 64-bit Acer on VirtualBox multiple times, but I would like to update to 10.6.6. Every time I do, however, I continue to get this annoying error, saying that the kernal and OS version mismatch, and the OS Version is no longer set. What is the proper way to update to Mac OS 10.6.6 because I have heard of it being done before.

Thanks in advance for your help, Thommaye

Comment: "Hackintosh" questions are [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a Mac OS virtually on non-Apple hardware is always a cat and mouse game. Because 10.6.6 was just released it may not be compatible with the virtual machine. You will most likely need to wait until a patch is devised and released.

You could try the solution outlined here: http://www.iphonemodding.com/forum/showthread.php?4644-Mac-Snow-Leopard-in-VirtualBox